# How to write BLE write characteristic over 512B

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a client attempting to send images to a server over BLE.

## Client Code

```
 //BoilerPlate to setup connection and whatnot

sendFile.onclick = async () => {
var fileList = document.getElementById("myFile").files;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
if (fileReader && fileList && fileList.length) {
   fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
   fileReader.onload = function () {
      var imageData = fileReader.result;

      //Server doesn't get data if I don't do this chunking
      imageData = imageData.slice(0,512);

      const base64String = _arrayBufferToBase64(imageData);

      document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
    
      sendCharacteristic.writeValue(imageData);
   };
}
};
```

## Server Code

```
    MyCharacteristic.prototype.onWriteRequest = function(data, offset, withoutResponse, callback) {
  
     //It seems this will not print out if Server sends over 512B.
     console.log(this._value);
};
```

My goal is to send small images (Just ~6kb)...These are still so small that'd I'd still prefer to use BLE over a BT Serial Connection. Is the only way this is possible is to perform some chunking and then streaming the chunks over?

## Current 'Chunking' Code

```
const MAX_LENGTH = 512;
for (let i=0; i<bytes.byteLength; i+= MAX_LENGTH) {
    const end = (i+MAX_LENGTH > bytes.byteLength) ? bytes.byteLength : i+MAX_LENGTH;
    const chunk = bytes.slice(i, end);
    sendCharacteristic.writeValue(chunk);
    await sleep(1000);
}
```

The above code works, however it sleeps in between sends. I'd rather not do this because there's no guarantee a previous packet will be finished sending and I could sleep longer than needed.

I'm also perplexed on how the server code would then know the client has finished sending all bytes and can then assemble them. Is there some kind of pattern to achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

BLE characteristic values can only be 512 bytes, so yes the common way to send larger data is to split it into multiple chunks. Use "Write Without Response" for best performance (MTU-3 must be at least as big as your chunk).

Comment: May you please provide some sample code or a tutorial, thanks